# Form element Iteration, in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a code snippet for a template module that I have been creating and I've hit a wall so to speak. I'm trying to loop through all textareas on my page, and apply formatting with some very basic validation.

Javascript is not my strongest suit but I can understand it to a point, my question is how do I collect the ID's and then use them to apply the formatting.

For example,

```
for each (textarea) 
{
    collect character restriction from html
    display character restriction in a formatted manner
}
```

I have included my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grhLupp7/1/) which I have been using to build this snippet.

Comment: You can use `getAttribute('id')` to get the id of the object: https://jsfiddle.net/grhLupp7/2/. However, you're already collecting all the textareas in `count`. Just access them via `count[i]`

Comment: @eithedog `el.id` <- This is shortest

Comment: I could access them via the index, but it would be numeric, how would i capture the ID's ?

Comment: I was going to ask, is jQuery an option? Because then it would be so trivial. A little selector, apply some style, use a tiny plugin for max text length, job done. But then, I noticed jQuery's `$function()` at the end of the code, so.... why not use it all the way?

Comment: @TheProHands aye, I keep making my life harded :D, @Beaniie - no, `i` is the index, `count[i]` is the textarea. Have a look at linked fiddle, I've put in a line that `console.log`s retrieval of id. And as @TheProHands pointed out you can use `count[i].id` to retrieve id as well

Comment: @JeremyThille I tried to keep it away from jquery as the majority of all the code elements in the is project are Pure JS. Just keeping it consistant. Thanks for pointing out my hiccup. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've based on @FodorZoltán's class. My class does now:

- append the counter below the textarea;
- position the counter in the below part of the textarea;

Yeah, I'm lazy and the code has grown up. I added some events and renamed the class name to `"TextAreaRanger"`. It's working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/grhLupp7/3/):

```
var TextAreaRanger = function(input) {

    this.MAX = parseInt(input.getAttribute('maxlength'));
    this.INPUT = input;

    // add input events
    input["oncut"] =
    input["onpaste"] =
    input["onkeydown"] =
    input["onkeyup"] = this.update.bind(this);

    // create wrapper element
    this.wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    this.wrapper.innerHTML = 'Chars left: '+ (this.MAX - input.value.length);

    /* input parent element */
    var ipar = input.parentNode;

    // find input's i
    for (var i = 0, el; el = ipar.children[i]; i ++) {
        if(el === input) break;
    }

    // append wrapper below the input
    if (ipar.children[++i]) {
        ipar.insertBefore(this.wrapper, ipar.children[i]);
    } else ipar.appendChild(this.wrapper);

    /* stylize wrapper */
    this.wrapper.style.position = "relative";
    this.wrapper.style.color = '#f00';
    this.wrapper.style.fontSize = '11px';
    this.wrapper.style.left = (input.offsetLeft + (input.offsetWidth - 100)) + "px";
    this.wrapper.style.top = (-parseInt(this.wrapper.style.fontSize) * 2) + "px";
};

// Update the counter
TextAreaRanger.prototype["update"] = function() {
    this.wrapper.innerHTML = 'Chars left: ' + (this.MAX - this.INPUT.value.length);
};
```

Comment: It's quite jarring to see how others work, this is quite elegant in my opinion. I think i need to research Javascript classes a bit more among other aspects before I fully understand your answer. Thank you for your assistance with this. :)

Comment: @Beaniie Oh... classes aren't a solution for this, but they're recommended to store less data in the JavaScript memory, that's because every class (*function*) contain the `prototype` object where it's possible to store values or methods which can be used in a instance of the same class. `function A() {this.call = function() { alert(1); };}; var a = new A, b = new A;` is slower than `function A() {}; A.prototype.call = function() { alert(1); }; var a = new A, b = new A;`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a prototype class for this, that can be extended to do other things aswell:

```
var CharWatcher = function(input){
  this.max = input.getAttribute('max-length');
  this.input = input;

  input.onKeyDown = this.update.bind(this);

  this.wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  this.wrapper.innerHTML = 'Chars left: '+ (max - input.value.length);
  /* style wrapper element */
  /* append around input */
};

CharWatcher.prototype = {
  update: function(){
     this.wrapper.innerHTML = 'Chars left: ' + (this.max - this.input.value.length);
  }
};

/* Somewhere else */

var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for(var i = 0, l = textareas.length; i < l; i++)
    new CharWatcher(textareas[i]);
```